# Laravel Livewire emit event not fire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 8, Livewire 2.x
I am trying to using emit event, just created a simple button in my Livewire components

```
<button class="" wire:click="callme()">click me</button>
```

my component controller

```
    public function callme()
    {
        $this->emitTo('Components.CustomizeModal', 'callFn');
    }
```

Components/CustomizeModal controller

```
    protected $listeners = [
        'callFn' => 'whatever'
    ];

    public function whatever()
    {
        dd("OK");
    }
```

It was fired and the response is

```
{
    "effects": {
        "html": null,
        "emits": [
            {
                "event": "callFn",
                "params": [],
                "to": "Components.CustomizeModal"
            }
        ],
        "dirty": []
    },
    "serverMemo": {
        "checksum": "479fe7f16b16351c610955960c8299f45fd4aeed72d69f9cded044e3bff9a525"
    }
}
```

it didn't fire the method at all, I have tried emit also, doesn't anyone has any idea?

Comment: Why you emit the event to Components.CustomizeModal? I mean, if the component who emit is the same type to listener, must be by its component's name, in your case CustomizeModal.

Comment: But it still doesn’t work, even I use $emit(‘callFn’)

Comment: mmm...that must work. Do you have the component's blades code inside div containers?

Comment: My original component works, I have button, it shows properly, and it sends ajax when I click, but the listener just not fired. let me install a fresh Laravel and try again, see any luck. I really don't understand it just a really basic function, should work in the hood.

Comment: I tried to install a refresh Laravel, but still don't work!!!

Comment: Please check the hierarchy of your components, emitTo is working well in parent child relation

Comment: I also tried put everything on the root, if I use emit only, it will match fire with name of the listener right? I don't know why it's complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can try to emit the event directly from the button.

```
<button wire:click="$emitTo('Components.CustomizeModal', 'callFn')">
```

and make sure

> Components.CustomizeModal

is qualified livewire component and also mounted when the event is emitted otherwise it will fail

Comment: I didn't add the component into the parents component, that's the case. Now emit is work fine, but still cannot use emitTo.