# How do I know if an event was fired? Looks like it didn't

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a `UserShow` component which shows the user's data (name, email, etc.) and also the actions he made in the site via relations (messages written, likes given, etc.). Now I want to allow user to change some of his data (name, email, etc.), so I wrote another component called `UserEdit` here is the form, validation, etc. It's working fine.

Since I'm using Livewire/Alpine I have some logic like

```
<div x-data="{ isEditing = @entangle('isEditing) }">
    <section x-show="!isEditing" />
        ...All user data...
        <button x-on:click="isEditing=true">
    <section>

    <section x-show="isEditing">
        <livewire:user.user-edit :user="$user" />
    </section>
</div>
```

So this works - it opens the component where the user will edit his data. In the component by the form's end, I have two buttons:

```
<div>
  <button type="submit">update</x-gui.button>
  <button type="button" wire:click="canceled">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The canceled function in the component is:

```
public function canceled() {
  Log::info('Canceling Edit');
  $this->emitUp('canceled');
}
```

Now, in the parent element I have the listeners ans the function defined as:

```
protected $listeners = ['canceled' => 'restart'];

public function restart() {
  Log::info('canceled received');
}
```

When I click the cancel method in the component, I see the first log "Canceling Edit", but I don't see the "canceled received" message

Am I doing something wrong? How do I know if the "canceled" event is even being fired?

- I have tried using `$emit('canceled')` from the button, but same thing without the log happens
- I have also tried [Laravel Livewire emit event not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67289143/laravel-livewire-emit-event-not-fire)

Comment: Are all your components using a single root div? Do you have your `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` positioned correctly? Can't see any issues with the given code nor with the flow.

Comment: Yeah I found the problem, was nothing related to what I asked  it should be a cautionary tale...

Comment: I see, yes you should always key nested components, it's even in the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-cures). If you had added that info to the original question, I could have mentioned it ;)

Comment: Yeah I know, it took me hours to debug. I knew I had to key components when you're interacting with them, not when using to display them. That's what I thought. I never thought it was going to manifest somewhere else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what happened, and it was a very strange behaivour, so it tooks ages to debug.

The problem in this very specific component is that it was displaying all the messages inside a foreach, like:

```
<div x-data="{ isEditing = @entangle('isEditing) }">
    <section x-show="!isEditing" />
        ...All user data... <=== PRECISELY HERE!!!
        <button x-on:click="isEditing=true">
    <section>

    <section x-show="isEditing">
        <livewire:user.user-edit :user="$user" />
    </section>
</div>
```

The all user data had a `@foreach()` that was rendering another component:

```
@foreach($user->messages as $message)
    <livewire:message-card :message="$message" />
@endforeach
```

The problem was this livewire component wasn't being keyed, and this caused all kind of strange things to happen, chaging the line as below, solved the problem

```
<livewire:message-card :message="$message" :key="$message->id" />
```

So, the cautionary tale is: **Always key your components inside a loop, even when they are just for displaying information, and not to be acted upon them**